# cakephp - don't change null field on update

Tags: php, cakephp

i use cakephp 2.5.4 and want when update record in database, fields that is null, do not change

this is my update function

```
...
   if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
       return $this->User->id;
   }
...
```

Comment: what is wrong at the moment ?

Comment: when empty string set in model, change previous value, that is wrong in my business!

Comment: u mean if say User address is NULL in DBase , Then no matter what i enter in Address in Html , Update wont update Address , correct? it will be NULL in db.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before saving your data, remove your empty values from the array.

```
foreach ($this->request->data as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value))
        unset($this->request->data[$key]);
}

if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
   return $this->User->id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the condition -

```
$conditions = array(
               'conditions' => array('my_field IS NOT NULL')
              );

$this->User->updateAll($this->request->data, $conditions);
```

and you dont need `$this->User->getLastInsertId();`, you will get it by `$this->User->id;`

Comment: Second parameter of method `save()` can't be an array of conditions. It can be either a `boolean $validate` or an array or `$params` which none of them is conditions. Maybe you meant to say `UpdateAll()`.

Comment: thank for answer, but not work yet, i want when empty string set in model, previous value not change

Comment: ohhh.. then you have to built the array like this. if empty then remove the field from data array.